# How to disable automatic download of new podcast episodes in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, downloads, podcast

After adding a new podcast to Rhythmbox it starts downloading the newest episode automatically without asking the user for permission.

I do find this behaviour pretty annoying especially when you have a lot of podcasts and are using 3G broadband to access the internet.

Can you update the podcast feed and then choose manually which episode you want to download? Did not find this in the settings/preferences...

Comment: If you think your question was answered right please mark the answer with the green arrow.

Answer (score 3):

Run Rhythmbox then Edit menu -- Preferences  -- Podcasts tab -- Check for new eposodes and select Manually.

Comment: Just wanted to say how that is counter-intuitive. "Check" for new episodes is very different from "Download" new episodes. (I used to use Amarok, but with Ubuntu 11.10, I am trying new things. I didn't like the lack of customization of Banshee, so am trying Rhythmbox.)

Comment: This doe snot seem to do it. The podct are still downloading when I start Rhythmbox even though it is set to Manual in Preferences -> Podcast Tab

Comment: This does not answer the question, which it seems can only correctly be answered by stating that no, it is not currently possible.